# regex: exlude one word from sentence

Tags: regex

I am beginner at regex and now I am trying to solve the following example:

I have this file below and I would like to match only the names.

```
 @misc{diaz2006automatic,
  title={AUTOMATIC ROCKING DEVICE},
  author={Diaz, Navarro David and Gines, Rodriguez Noe},
  year={2006},
}

@article{gentsch1992identification,
  author={GenTSCH, JoN R and Glass, RI and Woods, P and Gouvea, V and Gorziglia}
```

I have created this regex : 
`(?<=author=\{).*[a-z](?=\})` but I am not able to remove "and" from the list of names.

Please, could you give my some advice? Thank you very much.

Comment: It will be easier to remove `and` after you collect your matches using string programming language means.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use any programming language because this example is for regex only. I started doing some online training and I got stuck on this.
I am not asking for solution just for some hint :)

Comment: The [a-z] character class isn't adding anything except to say the last character before the closing brace has to be a letter. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to delimit space with names between "author=" and } brace.

Comment: What is the regex library/flavor?

Comment: What are the expected matches? Try `(?:author=\{|\G(?!\A)\s*,?\s*(?:and\s+)?)\K[a-zA-Z]+`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jsZkeO/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to do it in "one command" is the following line:

```
sed -nr -e '/^\s*author=/ s/(\s*author=\{|\}|\s+and\s+|,)//pg'
```

Result:

```
Diaz Navarro DavidGines Rodriguez Noe
GenTSCH JoN RGlass RIWoods PGouvea VGorziglia
```

Here, by "one command" I mean one expression (the whole thing between simple quotes). Of course, this point of view can be disputed.

Explanation:

- `-n` : don't output the lines
- `-r` : use extended regexps
- `-e` : our expression:

  - `/^\s*author=/ [...]` Perform the next operation only if the line matches this regexp.
  - `s/(\s*author=\{|\}|\s+and\s+|,)//pg` The said expression. Removes what we don't want. A list of patterns separated by a pipe `|`. They can be viewed as "separators" for easy understanding.

Comment: Hi,
thank you very much for your help.